# send php text output to client browser and run rest in server side

Tags: php, mysql, return, echo

I have a straight forward php script thats performs one mysql query. Based on this i then run about 10 more mysql queries. I then return the result via echo to the client.

But to save time for the client I can echo the result out THEN run the remaining 10 mysql queries server side so the client gets a quicker response.

can this be done?  or does the client have to wait for the entire php script to executed server side before getting a text response?

Heres my code:

```
 $dbc = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
 if (!$dbc)  {  die('SERVER ERROR PLEASE CONTACT US FOR MORE INFORMATION!');  }
 mysql_select_db("$db_name", $dbc);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE (`status` LIKE 'active%' OR `status` LIKE 'featured%')  ORDER BY `clicks` DESC LIMIT 10;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$dbc);
 $totalads=mysql_num_rows($result);
 $str="";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
  $str .= $row["banner"] . "][".  $row["link"] . "<BR>";

  //the code below is used to update stats but can be run after output to client
  $views=$row["views"];  $targetviews=$row["targetviews"];
  if (intval($views)+1 >= intval($targetviews))
   {
   $sql1 = "UPDATE `ads` SET `views` = `views` + 1 , `status` = 'expired' WHERE `ID`=".$row["id"].";";
   }
  else
   {
   $sql1 = "UPDATE `ads` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `ID`=".$row["id"].";"; 
   }
  $result2 = mysql_query($sql1,$dbc);
  mysql_free_result($result2);
  }

 $str=rtrim($str,"<BR>");
 mysql_free_result($result);
 mysql_close($dbc); 
 die ($str);
```

Comment: There is no reason that you need to make 10 additional queries. In fact, with a little creative thinking you could do all this with a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is completely possible with the use of ob_start(); Take a look here... http://www.php.net/ob_start and that will give you an idea. I don't know what your code looks like but as an example you could do something like this...

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $results = DB::get()->query($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";
    $content = ob_get_content();
    @ob_end_clean();
    echo $contents;
    //continue processing
```

obviously you need to tailor that for your specific script but that is an idea to get you where you need to go

~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~

OK so using your code and comments here you go.
First, yes you can do more than one while loop with the results, though you shouldn't as that is bad coding practices.
That being said here is what I would do...

```
ob_start();
$level = ob_get_level();
$dbc = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
 if (!$dbc)  {  
    die('SERVER ERROR PLEASE CONTACT US FOR MORE INFORMATION!');  
 }
 mysql_select_db("$db_name", $dbc);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ads` 
            WHERE (`status` LIKE 'active%' OR `status` LIKE 'featured%')  
        ORDER BY `clicks` DESC LIMIT 10;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$dbc);
 $totalads=mysql_num_rows($result);
 $str="";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $str .= $row["banner"] . "][".  $row["link"] . "<br />";
     $views[] = $row['views'];
     $target_views[] = $row['targetviews'];
     $ids[] = $row['id'];
 }
 echo $str;
 $content = ob_get_contents();
 if(ob_get_level() > $level + 1) {
     ob_end_flush();
 }
 echo $content;
 @ob_end_clean();
 for($i = 0, $len = count($views); $i < $len; $i++) {
     if((intval($views[$i] + 1) >= intval($target_views[$i]) {
         $sql = "UPDATE `ads` 
                 SET `views` = `views` + 1 , 
                 `status` = 'expired' 
                 WHERE `ID`=".$ids[$i].";";
     } else {
         $sql = "UPDATE `ads` 
                 SET `views` = `views` + 1 
                 WHERE `ID`=".$ids[$i].";";
     }
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     mysql_free_result($result);
 }
 //I don't know what this stuff here is for except for the close line, but it's her if you want it
 $str=rtrim($str,"<BR>");
 mysql_free_result($result);
 mysql_close($dbc); 
 die ($str);
```

?>

You no longer need the die statement there, but I left it incase you wanted it for something else. That should do what you need, check my stuff for typos though I just kinda pushed it out real quick for ya. please don't forget to mark that little check box for the right answer if it works, or leads you to the solution. Thanks man

Comment: this looks useful, il try it, ive updated my first post with my code

Comment: You are going to run into problems because the code you have that you say can be run later is inside of the while loop. Your best bet on this is to store values in an array in the while loop, then build your string and output that, then do your other things. Let me know if you want me to write some sample code for you

Comment: i know that.  I was just thinking now is it worth it.  the code is to return urls to an android phone that uses web.get method.  I tried the script in phone browser and it loaded fast.  But when using a 3G network every seconds counts as its slower speed.  So it could help.  

what i want to know is could i build $str using one while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) loop, output it, flush(), then use another while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  loop to do the mysql queries after output.  or does fetch_assoc clear the result on by one, thus needing to run the query again?

Comment: I think if you could do an example on using the array method you mentioned i would use that if the above is true

Comment: solution is above, check it for typos and stuff and you may need to tweak it a little to suit your needs, but that should work for ya

Comment: well i use rtirm as i dont want the last <BR/> as i use that to split each ad.  also is it necessary to use mysql_close($dbc);

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're creating a website. So, you can run the 10 others queries in a AJAX call, launch at the loading of the page.

Your architecture will be:

- main.php which run 1 query and return the HTML page with data of the query ;
- long_query.php which run the other queries in background ;
- page.html which present first query results and with some javascript called the `long_query.php` script to get the result of other queries.

You need for this to write some javascript which will [run an AJAX call](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), get the data and modify the current HTML page to add the data returned. If you're already using jQuery on your project, you can use [`jQuery.ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: not true, with the use of output buffering and forcibly flushing with end_clean or end_flush you can echo content to the browser while php is continuing to process, I have written several scripts like this that ran 24/7 and sent output after every single job as special cron services to run deralict tasks

Comment: Interesting, I knew I can do that in Python but not in PHP (buffer management in PHP always gives me headache). I remove what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You can as example run the first query.
Then return data to client.
From client run the 2°nd ajax call that will call a php page with the second script, etc....

Maybe the 2°nd ajax can call a php page that will launch the other 9 queries and then finally get the last reply needed.

Answer (score 0):

generate output string 
flush it 
and do less of code 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: "flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser."

Comment: flush alone won't work, it does on soe hosts but on the vast ajority of hosts you need to use ore powerful things like @ob_end_clean() and @ob_end_flush, after getting your content of course